# XSLT 2.0: selecting a sub-range of nodes. How?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have this in the file index.xml, that I transform with XSLT 2.0:

```
<numberGroup>
  <entry>
    <file>n1.xml</file>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <file>n2.xml</file>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <file>n3.xml</file>
  </entry>
  ..... many more entries
</numberGroup>
... and more numberGoups
```

In the stylesheet I have these two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="numberGroup">
<xsl:apply-templates select="entry">
  <xsl:with-param name="ngFiles" select="entry/file" tunnel="yes"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="entry">
   <xsl:param name="ngFiles" required="yes" tunnel="yes"/>
   ....
</xsl:template>
```

Now, select="entry/file" selects all files n1, n2, n3, every time the second template is executed for a "entry/file".
However, I need to select only the files up to and including the  "entry/file" preceding the file I call the template on. So when the second template executes for n1.xml, ngFiles is empty, when it executes for n2.xml, ngFiles has only n1, and when the template executes for n3.xml, ngFiles has only n1 and n2.
I thought maybe I could do something like:

```
<xsl:with-param name="ngFiles" select="entry/file[0 to .....]" tunnel="yes"/>
```

in the first template.
Any suggestions for the .... ?
maybe something with preceding::file or so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing a parameter you can retrieve the nodes you want from inside the `match="entry"` template using

```
preceding-sibling::entry/file
```

If you want to tunnel this value into other templates then do:

```
<xsl:template match="numberGroup">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="entry"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
  <xsl:param name="ngFiles" select="preceding-sibling::entry/file" tunnel="yes"/>
   ....
</xsl:template>
```

The `select` on an `xsl:param` is evaluated in the context of the template that contains it (i.e. the `entry` element is the current context item) whereas the `select` on `with-param` is evaluated in the context of the caller.